# How to do a tenant wide extension for classic view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-framework

I'm developing a End User License Agreement using spfx extension that is deployed as a tenant wide app.

the behavior is that when a user logged on a pop up will appear that they need to accept so they could proceed to their work. In modern view its already finished and as what i've researched spfx doesn't support classic view.

How could do it in classic view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For classic view, you could add script link by [PNP PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpjavascriptlink?view=sharepoint-ps).

```
Connect-PNPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev
Add-PnPJavaScriptLink -Name "name" -Url /sites/dev/SiteAssets/jsname.js -Sequence 9999 -Scope Site
```